# Android ViewModel incompatible callback and bundle scope

Tags: android, mvvm, callback, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

When the user interacts with a TextView in my MainActivity I invoke a `GamesBottomSheetDialog` and I pass it a list of available games so the user can select one :

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        gamesViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GamesViewModel.class);
        gamesViewModel.getSelectedGame().observe(this, new Observer<Game>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Game game) {
                //WAIT FOR THE USER TO SELECT A GAME FROM THE BOTTOM SHEET LIST
            }
        });
        initializeGameSelectorDialog();
    }

    private void initializeGameSelectorDialog() {
        binding.preview.tvGames.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            gamesBottomSheetDialog = GamesBottomSheetDialog.newInstance();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(GAMES, getAvailableGames());
            gamesBottomSheetDialog.setArguments(bundle);
            gamesBottomSheetDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "ModalBottomSheet");
        });
    }
    
    ...

}
```

Then my `GamesBottomSheetDialog` simply instantiates a `GamesViewModel` and observes the games until they are grouped (custom logic) and ready for display in the adapter:

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    public class GamesBottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
        
        private GamesAdapter gamesAdapter;
    
        private GamesViewModel viewModel;
        private BottomSheetGamesBinding binding;
    
        public GamesBottomSheetDialog() {
            //REQUIRED EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR
        }
    
        public static GamesBottomSheetDialog newInstance() {
            return new GamesBottomSheetDialog();
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            binding = BottomSheetGamesBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
            viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(GamesViewModel.class);
            viewModel.getGameItems().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<GameItem>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<GameItem> gameItems) {
                    GenericUtils.changeVisibility(View.GONE, binding.progressBar);
                    gamesAdapter.refreshAdapter(gameItems);
                }
            });
            ...
            return binding.getRoot();
        }

     ...

      //This method is a callback listener from the adapter:
     @Override 
public void onGameSelected(Game game) {
                gamesViewModel.setGame(game);
        }

    }
```

Since I need to provide Callback between my `MainActivity` and `GamesBottomSheetDialog` when the user taps on a game item inside the adapter, I need to create a "Shared ViewModel" attached to the Activity's scope:

```
@HiltViewModel
public class GamesViewModel extends ViewModel {

    ...

    @Inject
    GamesViewModel(GameRepository gameRepository, SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle){
        this.gameRepository = gameRepository;

        GameList gameList = GenericUtils.deserialize(savedStateHandle.get(GAMES), GameList.class);
        if (Objects.nonNull(gameList)) {
            games = gameList.getGameList();
        }
        selectedGame = new MutableLiveData<>();
        gameItems = new MutableLiveData<>();
        
        gameItems.setValue(groupGames(games));

    }

    ...

    public MutableLiveData<List<GameItem>> getGameItems() {
        return gameItems;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Game> getSelectedGame() {
        return selectedGame;
    }

    public void setGame(Game game) {
        selectedGame.setValue(game);
    }
 
}
```

However there is a big incompatibility problem here, if I set the ViewModel scope to the activity the callback works perfectly BUT the `SavedStateHandle` with the list of pre-populated games is always null in the `GamesViewModel` since the Bundle is scoped to the Fragment itself and NOT to the Activity. This means that if I change the scope from this:

```
 viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(GamesViewModel.class);
```

To this:

```
 viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GamesViewModel.class);
```

The `SavedStateHandle` in ViewModel is not null anymore, but now the callback doesn't work because the scope of the `MainActivity` is different from the one located in `GamesBottomSheetDialog`.

Is there any way to use my Bundle and the callback in a compatible way?